# Why does dvc push on a dracoon dataspace ran into a read timeout error after some minutes?

Tags: webdav, dvc

I want to save my data from a training of a ml model with dvc on a dracoon dataspace. At first glance it seems successfull, as some folders are created on my dracoon dataspace at the correct position where also some files are included. However after my dvc push runs a while, it ran into a "https.ReadTimeout" Error.

So here is what I have accomplished so far. I created a folder on my dracoon dataspace. In my repository I defined my dracoon folder via a webdav as my remote storage for dvc. I setup the dvc config file, so I can login with my dracoon user. I added my data folder and executed dvc push in my command line. After some time I get the following error:

```
dvc push -v
2023-07-06 11:30:15,478 DEBUG: v3.4.0 (pip), CPython 3.8.10 on Linux-5.15.0-69-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.29
2023-07-06 11:30:15,478 DEBUG: command: /home/buildserver/Documents/training/venv_test/bin/dvc push -v

2023-07-06 11:30:24,826 DEBUG: Preparing to transfer data from '/home/buildserver/Documents/training/.dvc/cache/files/md5' to 'files/md5'
2023-07-06 11:30:24,826 DEBUG: Preparing to collect status from 'files/md5'
2023-07-06 11:30:24,830 DEBUG: Collecting status from 'files/md5'
2023-07-06 11:30:24,845 DEBUG: Querying 3 oids via object_exists                                                                                                                                     
2023-07-06 11:30:26,450 DEBUG: Remote cache missing indexed .dir hashes 'd269d8676eeac1008ea5d73d45c93ad8.dir, a9f32fe0dc25e05cfeaa642c2ad55145.dir, 5ea31703977c3b8f1f80d9b2cefb34e2.dir', clearing remote index
2023-07-06 11:30:26,511 DEBUG: Querying 4 oids via object_exists                                                                                                                                     
2023-07-06 11:30:29,965 DEBUG: Estimated remote size: 256 files                                                                                                                                      
2023-07-06 11:30:29,965 DEBUG: Querying '6593' oids via traverse                                                                                                                                     
2023-07-06 11:30:31,885 DEBUG: Preparing to collect status from '/home/buildserver/Documents/training/.dvc/cache/files/md5'                                                 
2023-07-06 11:30:31,888 DEBUG: Collecting status from '/home/buildserver/Documents/training/.dvc/cache/files/md5'
2023-07-06 11:30:31,951 DEBUG: transfer dir: md5: a9f32fe0dc25e05cfeaa642c2ad55145.dir with 192 files                                                                                                
2023-07-06 11:40:17,730 ERROR: failed to transfer 'effd96f923720b1c81fa92f6c356fc72' - The read operation timed out: The read operation timed out: The read operation timed out
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/buildserver/Documents/training/venv_test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httpcore/_exceptions.py", line 10, in map_exceptions
    yield
  File "/home/buildserver/Documents/training/venv_test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httpcore/_backends/sync.py", line 28, in read
    return self._sock.recv(max_bytes)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1226, in recv
    return self.read(buflen)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1101, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/buildserver/Documents/training/venv_test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 60, in map_httpcore_exceptions
    yield
  File "/home/buildserver/Documents/training/venv_test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 218, in handle_request
    resp = self._pool.handle_request(req)
  File "/home/buildserver/Documents/training/venv_test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/connection_pool.py", line 262, in handle_request
    raise exc
  File "/home/buildserver/Documents/training/venv_test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/connection_pool.py", line 245, in handle_request
    response = connection.handle_request(request)
  File "/home/buildserver/Documents/training/venv_test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/connection.py", line 96, in handle_request
    return self._connection.handle_request(request)
  File "/home/buildserver/Documents/training/venv_test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/http11.py", line 121, in handle_request
    raise exc
  File "/home/buildserver/Documents/training/venv_test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/http11.py", line 99, in handle_request
    ) = self._receive_response_headers(**kwargs)
  File "/home/buildserver/Documents/training/venv_test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/http11.py", line 164, in _receive_response_headers
    event = self._receive_event(timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/buildserver/Documents/training/venv_test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/http11.py", line 200, in _receive_event
    data = self._network_stream.read(
  File "/home/buildserver/Documents/training/venv_test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httpcore/_backends/sync.py", line 28, in read
    return self._sock.recv(max_bytes)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/home/buildserver/Documents/training/venv_test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httpcore/_exceptions.py", line 14, in map_exceptions
    raise to_exc(exc) from exc
httpcore.ReadTimeout: The read operation timed out

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/buildserver/Documents/training/venv_test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dvc_objects/fs/generic.py", line 136, in _put_one
    return put_file(from_path, to_path, callback=callback)
  File "/home/buildserver/Documents/training/venv_test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dvc_objects/fs/callbacks.py", line 69, in func
    return wrapped(path1, path2, **kw)
  File "/home/buildserver/Documents/training/venv_test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dvc_objects/fs/callbacks.py", line 41, in wrapped
    res = fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/buildserver/Documents/training/venv_test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dvc_objects/fs/base.py", line 540, in put_file
    self.fs.put_file(os.fspath(from_file), to_info, callback=callback, **kwargs)
  File "/home/buildserver/Documents/training/venv_test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/webdav4/fsspec.py", line 374, in put_file
    return self.upload_fileobj(
  File "/home/buildserver/Documents/training/venv_test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/webdav4/fsspec.py", line 348, in upload_fileobj
    return self.client.upload_fileobj(
  File "/home/buildserver/Documents/training/venv_test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/webdav4/client.py", line 691, in upload_fileobj
    http_resp = self.request(
  File "/home/buildserver/Documents/training/venv_test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/webdav4/client.py", line 383, in request
    http_resp = self._request(method, path, **kwargs)
  File "/home/buildserver/Documents/training/venv_test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/webdav4/client.py", line 362, in _request
    http_resp = self.http.request(method, url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/buildserver/Documents/training/venv_test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 814, in request
    return self.send(request, auth=auth, follow_redirects=follow_redirects)
  File "/home/buildserver/Documents/training/venv_test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 901, in send
    response = self._send_handling_auth(
  File "/home/buildserver/Documents/training/venv_test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 929, in _send_handling_auth
    response = self._send_handling_redirects(
  File "/home/buildserver/Documents/training/venv_test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 966, in _send_handling_redirects
    response = self._send_single_request(request)
  File "/home/buildserver/Documents/training/venv_test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1002, in _send_single_request
    response = transport.handle_request(request)
  File "/home/buildserver/Documents/training/venv_test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 218, in handle_request
    resp = self._pool.handle_request(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/home/buildserver/Documents/training/venv_test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 77, in map_httpcore_exceptions
    raise mapped_exc(message) from exc
httpx.ReadTimeout: The read operation timed out
```

And that happens for many files. It cannot be a problem of authentication, as some folders and files are saved on dracoon. I also tried it with a local storage folder for dvc. There it could successfully store the data via dvc.

Does anybody know how I can successfully store my whole dataset to dracoon via webdav and dvc? Maybe I need to set some timeout parameters in the dvc library differently?

The versions I use are:

- dvc == 3.4.0
- dvc webdav == 2.19.1

I installed those libraries as follows: pip install dvc[webdav]

Comment: Could you try to set a higher timeout - `dvc remote modify myremote timeout 120`  (default is 30). Also, try to reduce the number of threads in `dvc push` (`-j` option I think).

Comment: thank this helped but has not solved my problem completely. My solution was to switch to an azure bucket as remote storage. Everything worked fine with the azure bucket.